# CMake does not link Boost correctly, but compiling from a terminal does

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, raspberry-pi4

I am running Ubuntu 21.04 on a Raspberry Pi 4b (8gb), and am using QtCreator for an IDE, with default settings, which landed on Clang as a compiler.

Most code (excepting libconfig) ran perfectly fine, but for reasons unknown to me, linking Boost::filesystem and Boost::system is proving impossible. See the minimal code below for the snippet I have been testing with:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    boost::filesystem::path full_path(boost::filesystem::current_path());
    std::cout << "Current path is : " << full_path << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I open a terminal on this source file, and run

```
clang++ main.cpp -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

I get an output that behaves exactly as one'd expect, reporting '/home/username/repo/boostsandbox/'.

Now, if I attempt to compile with CMake, using the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(boostsandbox LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

#   Compiler Options --------------------
add_compile_options(--verbose)

#   Package Management ------------------
find_package( Boost COMPONENTS filesystem system REQUIRED)
include_directories(... ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(... ${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})
message("Found Boost, {${Boost_LIBRARIES}}, at ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}")

add_executable(boostsandbox main.cpp)
link_libraries(boostsandbox Boost::filesystem Boost::system)
```

I receive the CMake parsing message 'Found Boost, {Boost::filesystem;Boost::system}, at /usr/include', and building halts at compile time, reporting the following:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/boostsandbox.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `boost::filesystem::current_path()':
/usr/include/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp:244: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::current_path(boost::system::error_code*)'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/boostsandbox.dir/build.make:133: boostsandbox] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:95: CMakeFiles/boostsandbox.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:103: all] Error 2
10:13:31: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
```

I am starting to feel like I've used every trick possible by now (including the C++11 enum define that gets Boost to work for some people), but I'm completely stumped. Please help!

TLDR:

Compiling with g++ or clang++, linking lboost_filesystem + lboost_system, building and executing functions perfectly. Building via the QtCreator IDE using CMake, compilation halts on a linking error, while Boost is found and linked.

Comment: Last line should be `target_link_libraries`, not `link_libraries`.

Comment: That has been right there, under my nose, for hours now. Thank you so much